# Problems setting up Alembic with Google Cloud Spanner

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic, google-cloud-spanner

I am trying to set up Alembic to work with Google Cloud Spanner, but no matter what I try I end up with one of the following errors when attempting to run a simple "`alembic upgrade head`":

- sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:spanner
- KeyError: 'spanner+spanner'

**I have tried so far:**

In alembic.ini for sqlalchemy.url:

```
spanner:///projects/<project>/instances/<instance>/databases/<db>
spanner+spanner:///projects/<project>/instances/<instance>/databases/<db>
```

In env.py:

```
config.set_main_option("sqlalchemy.url", "spanner:///projects/<project>/instances/<instance>/databases/<db>")
config.set_main_option("sqlalchemy.url", 
"spanner+spanner:///projects/<project>/instances/<instance>/databases/<db>")
```

I have tried with latest versions of SqlAlchemy/Alembic/SqlAlchemy-Spanner, as well as earlier versions (sqlalchemy 1.3 and matching versions of the others)

I have tried using sqlalchemy-spanner from PyPi and from GitHub `(git+https://github.com/googleapis/python-spanner-sqlalchemy.git@v1.2.0#egg=sqlalchemy-spanner)`

There is no code being executed so far, just trying to get Alembic to be able to connect to the instance.  I have all required permissions (project owner).

From what I can see, it appears that the spanner dialect for SqlAlchemy isn't installed properly.  I have tried to start a new project from scratch to elimiate old installations messing with my setup but no luck.

I've even tried to register the dialect manually through env.py with:

```
registry.register("spanner.spanner", "google.cloud.sqlalchemy_spanner", "SpannerDialect")
```

I'm by no means a Python expert (worked with Python for one year now after doing .Net/c# for 10 years), but I'm running out of ideas here.  Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose the issue is solved by a talk with Google Cloud Spanner team. In case if not, and to summarize, here is the explanation.

`sqlalchemy_spanner` now supports SQLAlchemy 1.3 and 1.4 versions, which are using different styles of connection URLs. It's described in [the docs](https://github.com/googleapis/python-spanner-sqlalchemy#database-url).

If `sqlalchemy_spanner` was installed by `pip install sqlalchemy_spanner`, the dialect should be registered correctly. If the package was installed from the GitHub repo, one should manually run the package `setup.py` file to register the dialect.

When one is working with Alembic, connection URLs and the dialect name still have to follow the style of one's SQLAlchemy version. That means in `env.py` (see [an example](https://github.com/googleapis/python-spanner-sqlalchemy/blob/c3b59077ff8d6d8916007bf204f90e1d1ed41c00/test_migration_env.py#L43-L44) in the repo) and in `alembic.ini`:

```
[alembic]
sqlalchemy.url = spanner+spanner:///projects/{project}...
```

Thus, if a similar error is failing, there are three places to check first: connection URLs and Alembic files `env.py` and `alembic.ini` - all must use the same dialect id to make it all work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  I eventually got it working (pretty much with the same code as in your examples).  When it comes to the actual Alembic migrations, these are incredibly slow (20+ sec to create a table, and up to 120 secs or more to create indexes or foreign keys).  Is this normal?  We are talking empty tables with less than 10 columns each, in a fresh spanner instance.

Comment: No, that's not how it usually works. Right now I have a project which performs operations lighting fast.

Maybe something related to a regional datacenter? Don't you know where your Spanner instance is regionally located? See the docs for more details:
https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/instance-configurations